# Anticommutative rules in Mathematica

Tags: mathematica

I am trying to create a product with the anticommutative rule in Mathematica using the operation $**$. I set in my rules the following line:

> before___ ** a_ ** b_ ** after___ :>   If[OrderedQ[{a, b}] == True,
>   before ** a ** b ** after,    before ** ((-1)*b) ** a ** after],
>   NonCommutativeMultiply[x_] :> x

This does half the job that I want, since it takes this output:

$$o_{1,2}\text{**}o_{1,3}\text{**}o_{2,3}-o_{1,2}\text{**}o_{2,3}\text{**}o_{1,3}-o_{1,3}\text{**}o_{1,2}\text{**}o_{2,3}+o_{1,3}\text{**}o_{2,3}\text{**}o_{1,2}+o_{2,3}\text{**}o_{1,2}\text{**}o_{1,3}-o_{2,3}\text{**}o_{1,3}\text{**}o_{1,2}$$

To the following:
$$2 o_{1,2}\text{**}o_{1,3}\text{**}o_{2,3}-2 o_{1,2}\text{**}o_{2,3}\text{**}o_{1,3}+2 o_{1,3}\text{**}o_{2,3}\text{**}o_{1,2}$$

I ultimately want it to reduce to:
$$ 6 o_{1,2}\text{**}o_{1,3}\text{**}o_{2,3}$$

Comment: It would be better to ask the question at https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/

Comment: You are absolutely right, thank you.